# success message but user is not deleted from MongoDB database

Tags: node.js, rest, mongoose, async-await

I'm implementing user authentication in my Node REST API.

I have defined in the UserController a method to remove a user:

```
  async function remove(req, res) {
  try {
    User.findOneAndRemove({ _id: req.params.id });
    return res.status(200).json({
      message: 'user deleted',
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({
      error: err,
    });
  }
}
```

When I hit the route in Postman with an id from a user stored in the database, I get the success message: "user deleted"

However when I look in the database, the user is still there.

What am I doing wrong?

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

dough, forgot to put 'await' before User.findOneAndRemove ...